# SparkSQL : SQL.DataFrame.Aggregate function on multiple columns with different operations

Tags: dataframe, rdd, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to apply an aggregate function to join or add lists of tuples in columns of a data frame, when doing a group by?

My data frame looks like this:

```
+--------+-----+-------------+----------------+
|WindowID|State|         City|         Details|
+--------+-----+-------------+----------------+
|       1|   IA|         Ames|   [(524292, 2)]|
|       6|   PA|  Bala Cynwyd|       [(6, 48)]|
|       7|   AL|   Birmingham|  [(1048584, 6)]|
|       1|   FL|      Orlando|      [(18, 27)]|
|       7|   TN|    Nashville|  [(1048608, 9)]|
+--------+-----+-------------+----------------+
```

My goal is to group rows that have the same values in 'WindowID' and merge the content of columns 'State' and 'City' into list of strings and the contents of column 'Details' into list of tuples.

Result must look like this:

```
+--------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------------+
|WindowID|    State|                    City|                      Details|
+--------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------------+
|       1| [IA, FL]|         [Ames, Orlando]|      [(524292, 2), (18, 27)]|
|       6|     [PA]|           [Bala Cynwyd]|                    [(6, 48)]|
|       7| [AL, TN]| [Birmingham, Nashville]| [(1048584, 6), (1048608, 9)]|
+--------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

My code is:

```
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlc.createDataFrame(rdd, ['WindowID', 'State', 'City', 'Details'])
df1 = df.groupBy('WindowID').agg( // Here i want to do merge operation. )
```

How can i do this using spark sql data dataframe in python.

Comment: Updated the answer (Use collect_list Aggregate function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the data for the input dataframe:

```
data =[(1, 'IA', 'Ames', (524292, 2)),
          (6, 'PA', 'Bala Cynwyd', (6, 48)),
          (7, 'AL', 'Birmingham', (1048584, 6)),
          (1, 'FL', 'Orlando', (18, 27)),
          (7, 'TN', 'Nashville', (1048608, 9))]
table = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ['WindowId', 'State', 'City', 'Details'])
table.show()
+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+
|WindowId|State|       City|    Details|
+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+
|       1|   IA|       Ames| [524292,2]|
|       6|   PA|Bala Cynwyd|     [6,48]|
|       7|   AL| Birmingham|[1048584,6]|
|       1|   FL|    Orlando|    [18,27]|
|       7|   TN|  Nashville|[1048608,9]|
+--------+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

Using collect_list Aggregate function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list
table.groupby('WindowId').agg(collect_list('State').alias('State'),
                              collect_list('City').alias('City'),
                              collect_list('Details').alias('Details')).show()
+--------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|WindowId|   State|                City|             Details|
+--------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|       1|[FL, IA]|     [Orlando, Ames]|[[18,27], [524292...|
|       6|    [PA]|       [Bala Cynwyd]|            [[6,48]]|
|       7|[AL, TN]|[Birmingham, Nash...|[[1048584,6], [10...|
+--------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
```